# use gcc compile a project that shows "undefined reference to `abort'"

Tags: c, linux, printf, variadic-functions

I wrote a printf myselef that use va_list/va_arg/va_start/va_end/va_arg.

```
typedef char *va_list;
#define  _AUPBND                (sizeof (acpi_native_int) - 1)
#define  _ADNBND                (sizeof (acpi_native_int) - 1)
#define _bnd(X, bnd)            (((sizeof (X)) + (bnd)) & (~(bnd)))
#define va_arg(ap, T)           (*(T *)(((ap) += (_bnd (T, _AUPBND))) - (_bnd (T,_ADNBND))))
#define va_end(ap)              (void) 0
#define va_start(ap, A)         (void) ((ap) = (((char *) &(A)) + (_bnd (A,_AUPBND))))
```

At first,I copy these macros from linux kernel and the printf can print 32-bit integer correct but cannot print 64-bit integer and print double/float may fail or collapse.Then I check the code and I guess the va_* may have errors,so I use __builtin_va_* instead of kernel's va_*.

```
typedef __builtin_va_list va_list;
#define va_start(v,l)   __builtin_va_start(v,l)
#define va_end(v)       __builtin_va_end(v)
#define va_arg(v,l)     __builtin_va_arg(v,l)
```

But gcc prompt "undefined reference to `abort'",so I write a empty abort() and myprintf works corretly.
My questions are:

1. Why linux kernel's `va_list/va_arg/va_start/va_end/va_arg` can not used for `printf` 64-bit integer and double/float?
2. When I used `__builtin_va_start/__builtin_va_arg/__builtin_va_end/__builtin_va_list`, why gcc prompt "undefined reference to `abort'"? But I can not find the definition of`__builtin_va_*`, where're their definition?

Comment: How about a <stdarg.h>? Also `_bnd` ( _bnd is supposed ot be _va_align) is defined differently in there: `#define __va_align(ty)     ((sizeof(ty) + sizeof(int) - 1) & ~(sizeof(int) - 1))`

Comment: Agree with @Armin; why are you not just using the standard header for va_arg stuff?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth indeed,our project is working without os support and we nead control where to print,so the stdio.h is not accord with our requirement.

Comment: @Ezio: Sure, I can understand lack of I/O support, but lack of *var-arg* support?

Comment: @Armin _bnd works with _AUPBND/_ADNBND(sorry,i forgot to post this) has the same function of __va_align.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth oh,no.I used va_arg,but when used __builtin_va_arg,gcc prompt lack of abort();

Answer (score 6):

Don't cut and paste things from the Linux headers. Instead, put this at the top of your source file:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
```

This will give you everything you need in order to use `va_list` and `va_arg`. However, it *won't* pull in `printf` or any of the standard I/O stuff (which lives in `<stdio.h>`).

Answer (score 1):

gcc's `__builtin_va_arg()` apparently will call `abort()` (at least on some platforms or situations) if it's invoked with a type argument cannot have been passed in the `...` part of the argument list for a function call.

For example, due to promotions a `char` or `float` passed as such an argument will have been promoted to `int` or `double`. Accessing those arguments as `va_arg(ap,char)` or `va_arg(ap,float)` is undefined behavior and gcc may call `abort()` in that situation - or it may do something else (my MinGW compiler will execute an invalid instruction to cause a crash).

You might see something like this when compiled:

```
In file included from D:\temp\test.c:2:0:
D:\temp\test.c: In function 'foo':
D:\temp\test.c:12:16: warning: 'char' is promoted to 'int' when passed through '...' [enabled by default]
  c = va_arg(ap,char);
                ^
D:\temp\test.c:12:16: note: (so you should pass 'int' not 'char' to 'va_arg')
D:\temp\test.c:12:16: note: if this code is reached, the program will abort
```

The 'definition' of `__builtin_va_*` is compiled into the compiler (that's why 'builtin' is part of the name).

As far as the Linux macros for varargs access: while the definitions you took from a linux kernel header do exist in include/acpi/platform/acenv.h, if you look carefully at the conditional compilation in effect, you'll see that those macros aren't used when building the linux kernel. I'm not exactly sure when those macros are in effect, but they won't work with x64/x86-64/amd64 builds because the ABI on that platform isn't entirely stack-based. See section 3.5.6 of the "System V Application Binary Interface - AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement" for details.